# Postfix can't send email reporting mail "Exceeded Mail Size Limit"

Tags: postfix, email-server

The errors:

```
Nov 30 04:58:26 serverm postfix/anvil[32747]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:*.*.*.*) at Nov 30 04:48:26

Nov 30 04:58:26 serverm postfix/anvil[32747]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:*.*.*.*) at Nov 30 04:48:26

Nov 30 04:58:26 serverm postfix/anvil[32747]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Nov 30 04:53:26
```

The attachment size is 75 MB. Any idea ?

Comment: a) None of the log lines you posted speaks about a size limit. b) 75 MB is too large for mail. Even if your own system accepts it, many recipient systems will not.

Comment: I can send emails around 10MB easily ... but this is the first time with this large. What do you suggest ?